# S3KeySensor issue: Despite passing host parameter in credentials file, task fails

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, airflow

Airflow version: 1.8

I am using an S3keysensor in my DAG. In airflow connections, I have pointed to a credentials file for AWS. I tried passing the 'host' parameter through the credentials file, as well as the airflow connections, but I am still getting the same error.

> 'BotoClientError: When using SigV4, you must specify a 'host' parameter'

**aws credentials file:**

```
host=s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com

access_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

secret_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

The host parameter is not an option in the credential file but it is an option of the class `boto.s3.connection.S3Connection`. So, if you set the code somehow like below, then you have to add the host parameter such as:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
conn = S3Connection(host=<HOST>)
```

or

```
import boto
conn = boto.connect_s3(host=<HOST>)
```

not in the credentials file.